# Auto use Numerictextbox instead of textbox for integer columns in Telerik Gridview [ edit mode ]

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

is there any good solution for Telerik gridview to use numeric-textbox instead of textbox when the column's datatype is int in edit mode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use GridNumericColumn instead of GridBoundColumn. Note that the data type of the data field in your datasource should be of integer type and NOT string.
More information is available here:
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-column-types.html

I hope this will help. Let me know if you need more info.